# Toggle Like Button Colour using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

A like button is clicked under a post. If its clicked it goes orange otherwise it's green. I cannot get the colours to toggle. How do I do this with an AJAX request querying data from a MySQL database?

I've tried using jQuery to amend the css file using the toggle attribute. I've also tried querying the database to see if the user has liked the post and set that result to a variable to use in the AJAX function(data).

NB. Code to protect against hacking attempts removed for demo simplicity.

Index php file:

```
        <?php
            $userid = session_id();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $postid = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $content = $row['content'];

                // Checking user status
                $status_query = "SELECT count(*) as type FROM likes WHERE userid='".$userid. "'" .  "and postid=".$postid;
                $status_result = mysqli_query($con,$status_query);
                $status_row = mysqli_fetch_array($status_result);
                $type = $status_row['type'];

                // Count post total likes and unlikes
                $like_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntLikes FROM likes WHERE postid=".$postid;
                $like_result = mysqli_query($con,$like_query);
                $like_row = mysqli_fetch_array($like_result);
                $total_likes = $like_row['cntLikes'];

        ?>

                <div class="post">
                    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                    <div class="post-text">
                        <?php echo $content; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-action">

                        <input type="button" value="Like" id="like_<?php echo $postid . "_" . $userid; ?>" class="like" style="<?php if($type == 1){ echo "color: #ffa449;"; } ?>" />&nbsp;(<span id="likes_<?php echo $postid . "_" . $userid; ?>"><?php echo $total_likes; ?></span>)&nbsp;

                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</body>
```

Ajax jQuery:

```
$(".like").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;   // Getting Button id
    var split_id = id.split("_");

    var postid = split_id[1]; 
    var userid = split_id[2];

    // AJAX Request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'likeunlike.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {postid:postid,userid:userid},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var likes = data['likes'];
            var type = data['type'];

            $("#like_" + postid + "_" + userid).text(likes);

            if(type == 1){
                $("#likes_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","#ffa449");
            }

            if(type == 0){
                $("#likes_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","lightseagreen");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Calls php file:

```
$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

// Check entry within table
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntpost FROM likes WHERE postid=".$postid." and userid='".$userid . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$fetchdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count = $fetchdata['cntpost'];

if($count == 0){
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO likes(userid,postid) values('".$userid."',".$postid.")";
    mysqli_query($con,$insertquery);
}else {
    $updatequery = "DELETE FROM likes where userid='" . $userid . "'" . " and postid=" . $postid;
    mysqli_query($con,$updatequery);
}

// count numbers of likes in post
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntLike FROM likes WHERE postid=".$postid;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$fetchlikes = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$totalLikes = $fetchlikes['cntLike'];

$return_arr = array("likes"=>$totalLikes,"type"=>$count);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: @Dharman Thank you for your comment. I mentioned in the body of the question that this has been removed for the simplicity of the example code.

Comment: @Dharman no worries I understand. Apologies. I'm new to this as you guessed. Like many I've taken the code from an example on the internet. It had both like and unlike buttons and I managed to integrate session_id as userid, which works for what I want it to do. I'm struggling to change the colour of the like button though. Yes, you are correct there was not prepared statements in the code, but I did/do intend to add them. My thoughts were I wanted to get the code functioning at a base level before looking at that. Personally that's an easier way for me to learn. Would you please help?

Comment: Your `like` button have `id=like_...` but in your ajax code you have `$("#likes_...` i think here is typo you have extra `s` while referring to that `id` remove that it should work.

Comment: @Swati thank you. I think the like id relates to the input tag where as the likes id relates to the span tag. So I’m trying to change the colour of the like tag so I can change the colour of the word ‘Like’ when it’s clicked. Thank you for helping.

Comment: What did you get response from php in ajax ? try to print i.e  `console.log(data);` and check  onces.

Comment: @Swati thanks again for your support appreciate it! Worked it out in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amended the jQuery file as below. The jQuery was not hitting the correct tags before. I was also using Safari and needed to clear the cache to see amended changes to the page. Oops. Newbie.

```
$("#like_" + postid + "_" + userid).text(likes);

  if(type == 1){
    $("#likes_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","#ffa449");
            }

   if(type == 0){
     $("#likes_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","lightseagreen");
          }
```

to:

```
$("#likes_" + postid + "_" + userid).text(likes);

  if(type == 1){
    $("#like_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","lightseagreen");

                }

if(type == 0){
  $("#like_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","#ffa449"); 
                }
```